# How to Debug .net applications in windows mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-mobile

I am new to mobile application development.

How to Debug .net applications in windows mobile.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use Debug configuration and you should be able to run through active sync your application to your mobile device or emulator with break points etc.

If for some reason your breakpoints are not hit, then go and delete your bin/obj directories and also your mobile deployment folder, some times VS gets stucked... and it does not deploy your new files.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just debug it on **emulator** , works the same way. Just remember to cradle emulator in Device Emulator Manager. If you don't have emulator, download appropriate version, for example :

[WM6 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en)

You can emulate every single detail or the real device , battery level , WiFi connection , etc. Take a look at "Celural emulator" if you want to symulate sending text-messages or dail some number.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particulary difficult in Visual Studio, but if you do it with a real device, you'll need a lot of patience. As in "10 seconds per step".

Comment: I certainly don't see that.  It's faster on a device for me than with the emulator.

Comment: Never tried the emulator, but IMO debugging on the real device is sluggish.